# Instagram API. "Unable to reach callback url"

Tags: php, api, post, curl, instagram

Ok guys so here is the setup. I am developing a site for a festival and need to use the Instragram API. The client would like to automatically load pictures from Instagram that use a certain hashtag. No problem here, the instagram API supports this function and many more.

But when I try to make a subscription (via a cURL Post Operation) I get an error response that my callback-url is unreachable. But it is reachable. I can surf to it via the browser no problem.

My cURL operation looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);       
curl_close($ch);
```

and this is the response I get after executing the post operation above:

{"meta":{"error_type":"APISubscriptionError","code":400,"error_message":"Unable to reach callback URL \"...myUrl...\"."}}

Any instagram guru's online that know what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I've tried to subscribe in both my callback-url file/api aswell as in an apart php file.

Comment: "But it is reachable" - are you sure it is reachable _from the server_? Use wget or similar to test this, if you are able to SSH to the web server.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am having this issue, remote server but no joy.

Comment: I did but it was so long ago I'm afraid I won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your home computer to develop it make sure the callback url you provided to instagram's servers can be reached (from their side)

You may have a firewall on your computer (make sure you allow incoming connections)
Or try running your code on a remote server (if you're not already)

Comment: Could you give some idea of what the url is (you can black out some parts). Have you URL encoded the query strings? (Your browser would automatically do this if you paste it in)